# Azure Cognitive Search results doesn't match SQL View result set

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Cognitive Search to query a data set to fetch Person information (Person Search) based on their first name and last name.

The data set within the index contains columns like FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Gender, SSN, Id, CreatedBy, Organization, etc. My query is returning the expected person as output but data in three columns, 'Gender, CreatedBy and OrgSlug', is incorrect.

query string: `search=Husband +App&searchFields=FirstName, LastName`

The view which is pointed to the index contains correct information: I checked this by running it in SQL. I have also checked Datasource connection string to make sure it is pointing to correct DB.

This is the result set which I am getting:

```
"value": [
{
            "@search.score": 9.847866,
            "FirstName": "Husband",
            "LastName": "App ",
            "DateOfBirth": "1985-09-26T00:00:00Z",
            "MiddleName": null,
            "Suffix": null,
            "OtherName": null,
            "Gender": null,
            "GenderId": "1",
            "SsnLastFour": "6789",
            "Ssn": "123456789",
            "PhoneNumbers": [],
            "RelationshipNames": [
                "Wife App "
            ],
            "Email": null,
            "Cin": null,
            "Mrn": null,
            "Street": null,
            "C2CMemberId": null,
            "Id": "PN-1abc7defg",
            "Tenant": "abcd",
            "Environment": "PR",
            "CreatedBy": "Supervisor",
            "OrgSlug": "SupervisorOrg"
        }]
```

Correct data for below columns should be:

```
"Gender": "Male",
"CreatedBy": "Assister",
"OrgSlug": "AssisterOrg"
```

This issue does not occur for all the search results but randomly! What do you think the issue is and How do I fix it?

Code of the View:

```
with cte as 
(select max(intakeeventId) id, PR.PersonId, PR.Value  FROM  [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR inner join IntakeData.Person P on P.PersonId = PR.PersonId where PR.QuestionId in (22,27) group by PR.PersonId, PR.Value),
ctefirstname as (select max(intakeeventId) id, PR.PersonId, PR.Value FirstName  FROM  [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR inner join IntakeData.Person P on P.PersonId = PR.PersonId where PR.QuestionId in (1) group by PR.PersonId, PR.Value),
ctelastname as (select max(intakeeventId) id, PR.PersonId, PR.Value LastName  FROM  [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR inner join IntakeData.Person P on P.PersonId = PR.PersonId where PR.QuestionId in (3) group by PR.PersonId, PR.Value)
select P.PersonNumber Id,
P.C2CMemberId,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 1 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) FirstName,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 2 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) MiddleName,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 3 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) LastName,
(select top 1 CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(PR.[Value],4)+LEFT(PR.[Value],2)+SUBSTRING(PR.[Value],3,2)) from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 6 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) DateOfBirth,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 4 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) Suffix,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 5 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) OtherName,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 78 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) GenderId,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 82 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) Ssn,
(select top 1 RIGHT(PR.[Value],4) from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 82 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) SsnLastFour,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 31 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) Email,
(select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 130 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) Cin,
'' Mrn,
(select [Name] from [Lookup].[IntakeOption] where BreId = (select top 1 PR.[Value] from [IntakeData].[PersonResponseWithValue] PR where PR.PersonId = P.PersonId and PR.QuestionId = 78 order by PR.IntakeEventId desc) and Type= 'GENDER') Gender,
(select top 1 IE.AddressLine1 from [IntakeData].[IntakeEventAddress] IE where IE.OriginatorPersonId = P.PersonId and AddressTypeId = 1 order by IE.IntakeEventId desc) Street,
(SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG (cte.[Value], ',') + ']' FROM cte cte where cte.PersonId = P.PersonId) PhoneNumbers,
(select '[' + STRING_AGG ('''' + ctef.FirstName + ' ' + replace(ctel.LastName, '''', '') + '''', ' ,') + ']' FROM [IntakeData].[ApplicationPersonRelationship] APR inner join ctefirstname ctef on ctef.PersonId = APR.PersonId inner join ctelastname ctel on ctel.PersonId = APR.PersonId where APR.RelatedPersonId = P.PersonId) RelationshipNames,
'abcd' Tenant,
dbo.usfgetserver() Environment,
P.CreatedBy,
(select top 1 OrgSlug from org.OrganizationUser OU inner join org.Organization O on O.OrgId = OU.OrgId where OU.UserName = P.CreatedBy) OrgSlug
from IntakeData.Person P
```

Data Types of columns in the view:

```
Id SHORT_STRING,
C2CMemberId  SHORT_STRING,
FirstName LARGE_STRING ,
MiddleName LARGE_STRING ,
LastName LARGE_STRING,
DateOfBirth datetime,
Suffix LARGE_STRING ,
OtherName LARGE_STRING ,
GenderId LARGE_STRING ,
Ssn LARGE_STRING ,
SsnLastFour LARGE_STRING ,
Email LARGE_STRING ,
Cin LARGE_STRING,
Mrn LARGE_STRING,
Gender LONG_STRING,
Street SHORT_STRING ,
PhoneNumbers LARGE_STRING ,
RelationshipNames LARGE_STRING,
Tenant LARGE_STRING,
Environment LARGE_STRING,
P.CreatedBy SHORT_STRING,
OrgSlug SHORT_STRING
```

Index definition (JSON):

```
{
  "name": "cx-person",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "FirstName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "LastName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "DateOfBirth",
      "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "MiddleName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Suffix",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "OtherName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Gender",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "GenderId",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SsnLastFour",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Ssn",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "PhoneNumbers",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "RelationshipNames",
      "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Email",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Cin",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Mrn",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Street",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "C2CMemberId",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Id",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Tenant",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Environment",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "CreatedBy",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "OrgSlug",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": true,
      "filterable": true,
      "key": false,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    }
  ],
  "suggesters": [],
  "scoringProfiles": [],
  "defaultScoringProfile": null,
  "corsOptions": null,
  "analyzers": [],
  "charFilters": [],
  "tokenFilters": [],
  "tokenizers": [],
  "similarity": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.BM25Similarity",
    "k1": null,
    "b": null
  },
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8BF1111111111\""
}
```

Data Source Definition (JSON):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://myservice.search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D9A11111111111\"",
  "name": "dscmspperson",
  "description": null,
  "type": "azuresql",
  "subtype": null,
  "credentials": {
    "connectionString": ""
  },
  "container": {
    "name": "[ViewGetPersonData]",
    "query": null
  },
  "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
  "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": null,
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "identity": null
}
```

Indexer Definition (JSON):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https:// myservice.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D8E11111111111\"",
  "name": "cx-person1",
  "description": "",
  "dataSourceName": "dscmspperson",
  "skillsetName": null,
  "targetIndexName": "cx-person",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": 0,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
    "base64EncodeKeys": false,
    "configuration": {}
  },
  "fieldMappings": [],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

Comment: Are you using an indexer to pull this data from SQL into your search index?  If so, are you using a query in your data source?  I wonder if this is a join filtering some info out...

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for your view and also the data types of the columns in your view as well as your index schema definition?

Comment: Could you also provide the data source json, which should look like the below, with connection string info eliminated?  I'm curious if you have anything in the "query" field.

Comment: {
  "name": "realestate-us-sample",
  "description": "",
  "type": "azuresql",
  "subtype": null,
  "credentials": {
    "connectionString": "REMOVE_THIS"
  },
  "container": {
    "name": "Listings_5K_KingCounty_WA",
    "query": null
  },
  "dataChangeDetectionPolicy": null,
  "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": null,
  "encryptionKey": null,
  "identity": null
}

Comment: Jennifer - I am using indexer. I have edited my question to add Indexer, Data Source, and Index definitions. Hope this will help.